# when will we hear the results of this court case?

Tags: united-states, law, us-state-laws, rule-of-law, state-legislatures

There was a senior who was suspended for self defense. He's suing the school. I heard the court was going to hear his case. This is really another question about the zero tolerance policy, but really I'm asking if anyone knows if there will be further news of this court case anytime soon. I heard it would return in April. This lawsuit was threatened in February.

http://www.theblaze.com/stories/2014/02/13/are-you-the-one-harassing-my-little-girl-thats-what-a-father-asked-right-before-things-spun-out-of-control/

I'm wondering if anyone knows when there will be further news about the court case, or if there's a way of checking up on the case. I think a lot of Westlake kids have sued the school, in different cases, but I'm wondering if there's a good chance we'll hear of the results soon. Or do you think it'll never be posted online?

Does anyone know when there will be further info available. Who do you think will win the lawsuit?

Comment: Remember what I said in meta about focus?  I can count 7  different question-like phrases in your post

Comment: These are the questions that i'm referring to

**I'm asking if anyone knows if there will be further news of this court case anytime soon**  -- **I'm wondering if anyone knows when there will be further news about the court case** -- **or if there's a way of checking up on the case** -- **I'm wondering if there's a good chance we'll hear of the results soon.** -- **Or do you think it'll never be posted online?**   -- **Does anyone know when there will be further info available** -- **Who do you think will win the lawsuit?**

Comment: @SamIam ... Yes...?

Answer (score 2):

Legal case information is generally easy to come by if you poke around a bit.  In this case, I just googled for the "Ventura County court" (per the article's description of where it happened), and then plugged the last name (Conti) into their [search](http://www.ventura.courts.ca.gov/via.html).  That produced the following links:

- [Reece Cole Smith vs Dominic Conti](http://www.ventura.courts.ca.gov/via/CaseInformationSummary.aspx?CaseNo=56-2013-00443499-CU-HR-VTA)
- [Reece Smith VS Lawrence Conti](http://www.ventura.courts.ca.gov/via/CaseInformationSummary.aspx?CaseNo=56-2013-00443496-CU-HR-VTA)
- [Gianna Marie Conti vs Reece Cole Smith](http://www.ventura.courts.ca.gov/via/CaseInformationSummary.aspx?CaseNo=56-2013-00443642-CU-HR-VTA)

There was to be a hearing on 4/7, but it was rescheduled. All three will be next addressed on 6/23/14.

Comment: Thx. What do you think the outcome will be?

Comment: That there will be further postponement(s) until no one cares.

Comment: @JackTrustsYou - I don't speculate on cases I know nothing about.  Facts I can research.  The future... not so much.  Opinions don't belong on a SE site anyway.

Comment: @JackTrustsYou - If you're curious, I just re-found this answer and checked:  [It was denied](http://www.ventura.courts.ca.gov/CivilCaseSearch/CaseReport/56-2013-00443642-CU-HR-VTA) on 7/31/14.